# Error using WordPress $wpdb object to get result from custom table

Tags: php, wpdb

I am trying to use $wpdb object to get results from a custom table and I get an error when I echo the result:

```
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$category in...
```

Here is the PHP code:

```
global $wpdb;
$prodCat = $wpdb->get_results( 
"SELECT * FROM product_category" , OBJECT_K);
    foreach ( $prodCat as $row ){
                echo $row->category-name;
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked your code and I think there are the couple of things you have to consider:

1. table prefix
2. column name
3. validate get_results function output

Firstly, the original prefix is defined in [wp-config.php](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#table_prefix). The WordPress [$wpdb class](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Class_Variables) provides a variable $prefix. Always use $wpdb obefore table name and it will automatcially insert the table prefix. Like this:`$wpdb->product_category`

Secondly, make sure column name is correct. You can view all columns names by dumping the get_results output. e.g: `var_dump( $prodCat );`

Thirdly, get_results return output as an array. If no data or Database error, the return value will be an empty array and if your query is empty or you pass the invalid output_type i.e: 'OBJECT_K', NULL will be returned.
So, always validate your output. e.g: `if( $prodCat )`.

```
global $wpdb;

$prodCat = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->product_category " , OBJECT_K);

if( $prodCat ) {

    foreach ( $prodCat as $row ) {

       echo $row->category_name;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think problem is in line

> echo $row->category-name;

It should be echo $row->category_name; if your query getting data.